# If a 2,400 lb. car is moving at 1 mile per hour, how much force is required to stop its motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, power

Given that I stand behind or in front of a car and someone will **move the car** from within at approximately 1 M.P.H., how much force is needed to stop the force driven by the engine to put the car at rest?

Someone gave a random guess that it's a 1 lb. per pound of car force. In other words, exactly the car's weight in force multiplied by the totality of miles per hour. Sounded a little too simple for me.

How does this figure?

Example:

[image]

This is not any homework assignment; this is just me randomly wondering, because I've stood behind cars reversing slowly and no amount of force I've ever observed can stop a car (from humans) even going at the slowest rate possible. I don't know how to get a sufficient answer, so I can't offer much.

Comment: Acceleration is a rate of change of velocity, so it should have units of `length/(time*time)`.

Comment: Might as well consider acceleration to be movement/speed since change of velocity is of no importance here (we have no need to measure its rate of change but its actual speed in relation to its weight and how much force will stop it). I don't believe F = ma will provide a sufficient answer.

Comment: Sounds like OP is trying to ask 'If a 2,400 lb. car is travelling at 1 mile per hour, how much force is required to stop its motion?' OP, there's a huge difference between travelling at 1 mph and accelerating.

Comment: In the picture illustrated above, the man is attempting to stop the motion of the reversing car (and failing). My question is basically an estimate of how much force is needed to have success with this in regards to speed/size. For example, a brick wall often stops a car in slow speed, but that's structural integrity and not strength of muscles.

Comment: @user121330 Agreed. Too often people use acceleration when they mean moving (while driving)

Comment: @user121330 Yes, that's a pretty close description of what I'm asking here. Traveling at 1 M.P.H. Rate of change is meaningless in this example.

Comment: @BenWaForGirls You might want to change your title, since a car cannot accelerate at 1mph.

Comment: @t.c Is it good enough now? I changed both the title and the description.

Comment: @BenWaForGirls Force is the time rate of change of momentum. Without specifying *how fast* you want your vehicle to stop, there is no way of telling *how much* force you need to exert.

Comment: @t.c I want it to stop at the exact rate of speed it was moving: 1 M.P.H. minimum.

Comment: The other variable here is the engine - if it's engaged, it will supply a force that grows as the speed drops below the original speed. I'm not sure how to stop at 1 mph without a conveyor belt, but I could stop from 1 mph to 0 mph (stopped) over half a second (some measure of time).

Comment: @user121330 Ok. How much **force** will it take to do so though, with your example specifically?

Comment: If the engine isn't engaged, any amount of force will eventually stop the car. If it is, the dynamics of the engine will determine that.

Comment: @user121330 So in short, you're not giving me an answer.

Comment: In short, you're asking an underdefined problem. That's why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: In order to relate a *force* to the velocity, a duration (i.e., length of time) needs to be defined. Are we talking 1s? 10s? An hour? Something else? Give us that, and then it can be computed.

Comment: To add to @KyleKanos, a duration *or* a distance (I want to stop the car before it travels another 1m, or 10m, or 100km) is what we're missing. But even with that, this is likely to get closed under the [homework policy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info), and see [this post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715).

Comment: Ben Wa, it appears that you may be working under a basic misconception. In the sufficiently idealized case you could stop it with the force applied by a feather if you were willing to wait long enough because force is not related to velocity it is related to *acceleration*. Until you have that basic fact clear in your head you will not even be able to frame a correct version of the question. That said, even the correct version is likely to get closed as too homework-like.

Answer (score 4):

Any force greater than zero can stop the car.  Only it will take longer and the distance moved by it by the time it stops also will be greater.  If the force is larger these parameters (time to stop and distance traveled before stopping) will decreasing.  Theoretically, infinite force is required to stop it instantaneously.

Comment: The math behind this: Momentum of car (mass $m$, velocity $v$) = $m\cdot v$. You need force $F$ for time $\Delta t$ such that $F\Delta t = m\cdot \Delta v$. Then the rest of the above follows.